# A set of n linearly independent vectors cannot be a subset of a vector space whose dimension is lower than n, how do I prove it?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

let $A =  {a_1,...,a_n}$   be a linearly independent set of vectors,
and let $B$ be a vector space such that $dim(B) < n$
Prove that $A \not\subset B$
or in other words that there exists atleast one  $a\in A,$ such that $ a\notin B$

I've been stuck on this for a few hours now, while it makes sense to me that it is true I just can't think of a way to prove it. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: **Hint :** Prove that if $A \subset B$, then $\mathrm{span}(A) \subset B$, and then $n= \dim(\mathrm{span}(A)) \leq \dim(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since every subset of a linearly independent set is linearly independent, it is enough to prove that if $v_1, \dots, v_{n + 1}$ are vectors in $\mathbb{F}^n$, then $v_1, \dots, v_{n + 1}$ are linearly dependent.

We can prove this by induction. The cases $n = 0$ and $n = 1$ are easy. The inductive step is essentially "column reduction" to reduce the last row of the matrix to have all entries $0$ except one so that we can use the inductive hypothesis.

If the $n$th component of each $v_j$ is $0$, then we can regard $v_1, \dots, v_{n + 1}$ as vectors in $\mathbb{F}^{n - 1}$ and we would be done by the inductive hypothesis. Thus we can assume some vector, say $v_{n + 1}$ has nonzero $n$th component $v_{n + 1, n}$, and we can assume $v_{n + 1, n} = 1$. For $1 \leq j \leq n$, set $u_j = v_j - v_{j, n}v_{n + 1}$. Then $u_{j, n} = 0$ for all $j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ so regarding the $u_j$ as vectors in $\mathbb{F}^{n - 1}$, by the inductive hypothesis there are scalars $c_1, \dots, c_n \in \mathbb{F}$ not all zero such that
$$c_1u_1 + \dots + c_nu_n = 0.$$
This means
$$c_1v_1 + \dots + c_nv_n - \sum_{j = 1}^{n}c_jv_{j, n}v_{n + 1} = 0,$$
the desired linear dependence relation for $v_1, \dots, v_{n + 1}$.